# Yolo3 on Image-net

Tags: conv-neural-network, darknet, imagenet

[Yolo version 3](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) is amazing new Deep learning neural network with pre-trained configuration and weights. However, the maximum classes it has is only 80 class from COCO dataset. There is another much larger dataset of [Imagenet](http://www.image-net.org/) with more than 22,000 classes.

Does anyone have trained Yolo3 (on Darknet) using Imagenet? Where can we get the pre-trained configuration and weights?

Comment: There is an available openimages pretrained model, which has 601 classes. https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

Comment: Note the maximum for YOLO is not 80 classes.  But the pre-trained weights that are offered for convenience on the repo for people to use are trained using the default 80-class MSCOCO dataset.